# If trace of $M=0$ ($M$ is given to be Hermitian), then prove that $M$ is a zero matrix or it is indefinite.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Question: $M$ is Hermitian and $tr(M)=0$, then prove that either $M$ is zero or it is indefinite.

The converse is obvious. i.e. if $M$ is a zero matrix, then $trM=0$.

However, I have no idea to prove the original problem that $trM=0$ implies $M$ is a zero matrix.

By the way, I understand trace of a positively definite matrix must larger than 0. However, I do not know how to prove the original problem too.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the context? it seems to be a missing hypothesis

Comment: Are we given that $M$ is a Hermitian (or symmetric) matrix?

Comment: @moo;Omn I'm sorry. It's my bad. The given $M$ is Hermitian. I presume that when we are talking about positive definite matrices, Hermitian(or symmetric) are our concerns.

Comment: @nam You should add that to the question.

Comment: @nam are you still stuck? What can we say about the eigenvalues of $M$?

Comment: @Omn Yup, I am still stuck with the question. I know that if $trM=0$, then there are two cases:
(i) all $\lambda_i =0$;
(ii) some eigenvalues are positive and some are negative, such that there sum is $0$.

Am I correct? But how do write it rigorously?

And, it seems that I have not used the given condition that $M$ is Hermitian.

Comment: @nan The fact that $M$ is Hermitian just lets you state that all the eigenvalues are real.  Here's what your proof should look like: if all eigenvalues are $0$, then $M = 0$.  If $M$ has a non-zero eigenvalue $\lambda$, then the sum of its other eigenvalues is $-\lambda$, so that there must be two eigenvalues of the opposite sign, so that $M$ is indefinite.

Comment: @Omn Thank you so much for your explanations. Your words in the second part are deep that it states the situation clearly.

Comment: @Omn I re-think this question. Even tr$(M)$=0, for example, $$\begin{pmatrix}
0 &1 \\ 
 0&0 
\end{pmatrix}$$
Trace of this matrix is zero, but it is not a zero matrix. At the same time, we can call it semi-positive definite, right? It's because its eigenvalues are larger than or equal to zero.

Of course, in some cases, it can be indefinte, likes:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
2 &1 \\ 
 0&-2 
\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: @nam: Remember that the matrix also has to be symmetric.  The only symmetric matrix with zero eigenvalues is the zero matrix (remember that all symmetric matrices are diagonalizable).  Neither of your examples are symmetric.

Comment: @omn I just come up with this **ugly** proof without using the hint symmetric:

If tr$(A)=0$, then it means that sum of its eigenvalues are zero. We assume that all of them are zeros.

Consider the eigenvalue problem $Ax= \lambda x$. Then we have $Ax=0$ because all the eigenvalues are zeros.

Then can we conclude that $A$ is a zero matrix?

Comment: @nam that only works if you use the fact that $A$ is diagonalizable.  For example, $\pmatrix{0&1\\0&0}$ has all zero eigenvalues but is not the zero matrix.

Comment: @omn Thank you for your example that $$\left(\begin{array}{cc|c}  
 0 & 1 & 0\\  
 0 & 0 & 0  
\end{array}\right)$$
And, I find that $(1,0)^{T}$ is the corresponding eigenvector (even thought $A$ is not a zero matrix).

However, I am confused that how you can come up with this counter example and how it is related to diagonalizability of a matrix?

Comment: @nam If a diagonalizable matrix has eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n$, then it is similar to the matrix
$$
\pmatrix{\lambda_1&&\\&\ddots&\\ && \lambda_n}
$$
So, if a matrix is diagonalizable with all eigenvalues equal to zero, then it is similar to the zero matrix, which means it is the zero matrix.

Comment: @Omn Thank you for your explanation and helping me many times. I finally work it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** The trace of a matrix is the sum of its eigenvalues.

Note that $M$ has a trace of $0$, it can be either the zero-matrix or indefinite; that is, it isn't necessarily the zero matrix as you have implied.  Note that Hermitian (or real-symmetric) matrices have real eigenvalues.

Comment: Take the $2\times 2$ jordan block with respect to $0$. What am I missing?

Comment: @GitGud symmetry, clearly.  I see your point.

Comment: As expected, you're right. The OP directed a comment at you in the question with this information. (+1)